# Autodeploy portlet in Liferay on Jelastic

Tags: liferay-6, portal, jelastic, autodeploy

I would to change the autodeploy folder to deploy my custom portlets in Liferay.
I using Jelastic setup with Tomcat. Have I to change the portal-ext.propeties?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 2 place I think you will have update the properties

1. **portal-ext.properties** update below properties to have your custom directory

   ```
   # Set the directory to scan for layout templates, portlets, and themes to
   # auto deploy.
   #

   auto.deploy.deploy.dir=${liferay.home}/deploy
   ```
2. For your plugin-sdk you will have to add below properties to your **build.{username}.properties**

   ```
   # Auto Deploy
   # Plugins will be deployed to this directory. Make sure that Liferay is
   # also set to scan this directory.
   #

   auto.deploy.dir=${app.server.dir}/../deploy
   ```

Hope this Helps !

Comment: Sorry "auto.deploy.deploy.dir" or "auto.deploy.dest.dir"? Where Can I find "build.{username}.properties" file?

Comment: You can find the buildXYZ.properties in your SDK folder. The portal-ext.properties is inside your Portal Folder, in the same level with the Tomcat folder

Comment: >Sorry "auto.deploy.deploy.dir" or "auto.deploy.dest.dir"? "auto.deploy.deploy.dir" is right here.

Comment: Michele if you go through liferay plugin sdk development guide https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installing-the-sdk  it mentions you need to create a property file with build.{username}.properties and inside this properties you mention your liferay tomcat path these properties can be found in default build.properties file. Basically you are extending or Updating the properties to take your changes.